# Relative layout - Right justify the data in textview

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I am using the following xml to generate a row in a list view. Though i have set the `gravity` as `center_Vertical` and `right`. Only `center_Vertical` is applied but not the "right" gravity. I have even tried inside the code. the "right" gravity is not working.  Kindly help me to correct the code.
Thanks in Advance
[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTicketID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"  
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"  
        android:text="Ticket ID"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCreationHour" 
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvTicketID" 
        android:text="Hour" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTableNumber"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvCreationHour" 
        android:text="Table #" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAmount"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"   
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvTableNumber" 
        android:text="Amount" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The code I use to create a row using the above `xml`

```
holder.tvTicketID.setText(String.valueOf(ticket.getId())) ;   
holder.tvCreationHour.setText(String.valueOf(ticket.getCreationHour())) ; 
holder.tvTableNumber.setText(String.valueOf(ticket.getTableNumber())) ;  
holder.tvAmount.setText(String.valueOf(ticket.getTotalAmount()))  ;
```

Comment: Post your actual layout design so we will help you more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I fonund the answer. I have changed the android:layout_width="wrap_content" in the TEXTVIEW to android:layout_width="30dp". Now it works..

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `android:layout_gravity="right"`

Comment: This is for the position in the layout. Am asking for the value inside the text view.

Answer (score 0):

In general, `android:gravity="right"` is different from `android:layout_gravity="right"`.

The first one affects the position of the text itself within the View, so if you want it to be right-aligned, then `layout_width=` should be either `"fill_parent"` or `"match_parent"`.

The second one affects the View's position inside its parent, in other words - aligning the object itself (edit box or text view) inside the parent view.

Comment: if i give fill_parent for the textview then except the first textview other 3 textview are out of the screen.

Comment: not to text view. its for layout. you can add your textview inside a relative layout and follow above steps.

Comment: Already for the Relative Layout i have given android:layout_width="fill_parent"